# mvc 6 generates antiforgerytoken only once

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am working with visual studio 2015 and aspnetcore rc2. I use `@html.antiforgerytoken()` in every form to post. But mvc 6 creates the first one and removes (or ignores,maybe) the others. I tried this with masterview and without master, no result. I am thinking that I have a mistake somewhere but where? I have cleared browser history and created a simple empty asp.net project with one view and one controller, tried again and no result again.

**Here are the screenshots.**

[image] output [image]  I do not use `@addtaghelper` or any other similiar extentions, I just use `@html.antiforgerytoken`.

Comment: i use this style for now, this is a particular solution not an answer: @{ if(viewdata["token"]==null){html.antiforgerytoken();} } and @viewdata["token"] inside form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github repo aspnet/MVC have a bunch of issues about multiple `AntiForgeryToken` calls: [#319](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/319), [#4595](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4595), [#4924](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4924). It seems that current behavior is a "effect" of previous bug. Opened [#5005](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5005).

Currently (as of 1.0.0 RTM) we have workaround: save generated token to variable and write this variable multiple times:

```
@{
    var token = Html.AntiForgeryToken();
}
<form id="form-one">
    @token
</form>
<form id="form-two">
    @token
</form>
```

**Update:** Issue [#5005](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5005) confirmed as bug, scheduled for [1.1.0 milestone](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/milestone/22).

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in [#5005](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5005#issuecomment-232085756), this situation occurs only when HTML and tag helpers are *not* used to generate the `<form>` element.

Other than switching to HTML generation i.e. using more invasive helpers, the easiest workaround is to add the following in your `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

or

```
@addTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: thank you for your response. as i mentioned in the question, I do not (want to) use @addtaghelper or any other similiar extentions

Comment: That's fine @ergen, it's a temporary workaround. We plan to fix [#5005](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5005) in our next release.